# ASP.NET MVC3 Multilingual website crashing on changing culture name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

n my multilingual website web.config file the culture is set to "be-by" (`<globalization culture="be-by" uiCulture="be-by"/>`)

There is a particular page "create.cshtml" that crashes at the **"model.Product.MaximumCapacity"** code given below

```
<tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.MaximumCapacity):
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.MaximumCapacity)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.MaximumCapacity)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

In this **"model.Product.MaximumCapacity"**, **MaximumCapacity** is a **column** that takes integer values in the **table Product**
The error message is **"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."**

If i go to the **ActionResult** function in the **controller** of this "create.cshtml", i see "NULL" being retrieved for the "MaximumCapacity" column.

But the issue is, this crash is happenning only for the culture "be-by"(Country is Belarus) and not for any other culture i am using for my website.

Further when i replace **"model.Product.MaximumCapacity"** with another column say **"model.Product.AbsoluteValue"** where AbsoluteValue is a column taking integer values and **ActionResult** function shows NULL values being retrieved,the application does not crash and the page displays fine for the 'be-by" culture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when the culture is set to "be-by" your database access code is having a conflict with the culture in your database. For example, your C# code might be using "be-by" but SQL Server might be using a different one, say "en-us".

I've seen issues when using Turkish "tr-TR" because the Turkish language has two "upper case I" characters and requesting a column like "CITY" becomes ambiguous (but "city" works OK.) Perhaps you are running into something similar with "be-by" culture where there is something ambiguous for MaximumCapacity but not for AbsoluteValue.

One way I've worked around this is by **changing only the UI culture** on the server rather than both culture settings.